# Given an array of 0s and 1s only and another array of ranges. return an array with number of zeroes in each set of range

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of 0s and 1s only and another array of ranges.
return an array with number of zeroes in each set of range.

Input

```
bits = [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
ranges = [[0,3],[1,4],[5,7],[4,8],[7,10]]
```

Output:

```
result = [1,2,1,2,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a helper array of the number of the zeroes until that point in the bits array.

```
bits = [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
sum  = [0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

result of [0,3] is then sum[3]-sum[0].

```
Make a helper array with the running sum of zeroes.
then subtract the the value at start of range from the value at end of range.
push result
repeat
```